# Text moving animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I am new to animations in JavaFX, and I get the basic idea of how it works; You need a starting keyframe and and ending one, then you play it.

What I want to do is have a list of strings, say, "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...10", and a variable, `index`. Then what I want to do is have 3 of them on the screen at a time like this inside 3 different `Text` objects:

```
0   1   2
```

In the example above, `index = 0`. If `index = 1`, it would look like this:

```
1   2   3
```

You get the idea, so what I want to do, is every time `index` increments (it would have to be a `Property`), there would be an animation of the numbers trading spaces.

So like this (symbol numbers represent fading):

```
index = 0 : 0   1   2
index = 1 : )  1   2#
frame --- : ) 1   2 #
frame --- : )1   2  #
frame --- : 1   2   3
```

So in theory, the lists that stores these numbers could be infinite so I can't (shouldn't) have a separate `Text` object for each number. I can't figure out how this should be done, as keyframes moving the `Text` object themselves complicates things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample.

[image: app]

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class NumberSwitcher extends Application {

    private static final int NUM_NUMS_DISPLAYED = 3;
    private static final Duration TRANSITION_TIME = Duration.seconds(0.5);

    private final IntegerProperty idx   = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    private final IntegerProperty toIdx = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);

    private final List<Label> labels =
            IntStream.range(0, NUM_NUMS_DISPLAYED)
                    .mapToObj(
                            this::createLabel
                    )
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    private final Button incrementButton = new Button("Increment");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setScene(
                new Scene(
                        createLayout(),
                        Color.PALEGREEN
                )
        );
        stage.show();

        enableTransitions();
    }

    private StackPane createLayout() {
        incrementButton.setStyle("-fx-base: darkslateblue; -fx-text-fill: papayawhip; -fx-font-size: 20px;");

        HBox numbers = new HBox(10);
        numbers.getChildren().addAll(labels);
        numbers.setPadding(new Insets(15));
        numbers.setMaxWidth(HBox.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        VBox layout = new VBox(
                15,
                numbers,
                incrementButton
        );
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(15));
        layout.setStyle("-fx-background-color: null;");

        StackPane centered = new StackPane(layout);
        centered.setStyle("-fx-background-color: null;");
        return centered;
    }

    private Label createLabel(final int i) {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setStyle(
                "-fx-font-size: 50px; -fx-font-family: monospace; -fx-text-fill: midnightblue;"
        );

        label.textProperty().bind(new StringBinding() {
            {
                super.bind(idx);
            }

            @Override
            protected String computeValue() {
                return "" + ((idx.get() + i) % 10);
            }
        });

        return label;
    }

    private void enableTransitions() {
        ParallelTransition changeNumbers = new ParallelTransition(
                createFadeFirst()
        );

        IntStream.range(1, labels.size())
                .mapToObj(this::createMoveLeft)
                .forEachOrdered(
                        moveLeft -> changeNumbers.getChildren().add(moveLeft)
                );

        changeNumbers.setOnFinished(e -> idx.set(toIdx.get()));

        toIdx.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                changeNumbers.play()
        );

        // You can disable incrementing while the transition is running,
        // but that is kind of annoying, so I chose not to.
//        incrementButton.disableProperty().bind(
//                changeNumbers.statusProperty().isEqualTo(
//                        PauseTransition.Status.RUNNING
//                )
//        );

        incrementButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            if (idx.get() != toIdx.get()) {
                idx.set(toIdx.get());
            }

            toIdx.set((toIdx.get() + 1) % 10);
        });
    }

    private FadeTransition createFadeFirst() {
        FadeTransition fadeFirst = new FadeTransition(
                TRANSITION_TIME,
                labels.get(0)
        );
        fadeFirst.setFromValue(1);
        fadeFirst.setToValue(0);
        fadeFirst.setOnFinished(e -> labels.get(0).setOpacity(1));
        return fadeFirst;
    }

    private TranslateTransition createMoveLeft(int i) {
        TranslateTransition moveLeft = new TranslateTransition(
                TRANSITION_TIME,
                labels.get(i)
        );
        double dx =
                labels.get(i).getBoundsInParent().getMinX()
                        - labels.get(i-1).getBoundsInParent().getMinX();

        moveLeft.setFromX(0);
        moveLeft.setToX(-dx);
        moveLeft.setOnFinished(e -> labels.get(i).setTranslateX(0));

        return moveLeft;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

*Answers to additional questions*

> I see you are translating the nodes, but, at what point do you change the location in the HBox?

Locations (e.g. layoutX and layoutY) in the HBox for this sample are never changed after they are initially laid out in the HBox.  HBox is a layout a manager, it will set the layoutX and layoutY co-ordinates of items in the HBox automatically.  The HBox layout algorithm will place each item in it's child list sequentially from left to right (by default) and size each item to it's preferred size.  The HBox works based upon dirty flags, so it will only re-layout the components inside when it needs to (e.g. the components change or the CSS style for components change or the available area for the HBox changes), none of which occurs in this sample.

> Are you just translating them, switching the text, then resetting the translation?

Yes.

> Could you just give a quick overview of how this works?

Three labels are added to a HBox.  A monospaced font and the same number of characters are used for each label, so each label is equal width.  Two indices are recorded.  One is the current index in the text area for the displayed characters, the other the the toIdx which is next index in the text array to be moved to.  An increment button is provided which will increment the toIdx.  A change listener is placed on the toIdx so that when it is changed, it kicks off a set of animations, the first animation fades first label, the other animations move the remaining labels to the next position left.  When the animation is complete, the translation of each label is set to 0, so each of the moved labels move back to their original position.  Also, once the animation is complete, the current index is set to the toIdx.  A binding is used to automatically update the text in each of the labels when the toIdx is updated.

The effect is that, when the increment button is pressed, the number in the first label fades, the numbers in the labels to the right move to the left, and once there, return to their original positions, but with their values set to the next highest number.  This provides the effect requested in the question.

Comment: I don't understand this, I see you are translating the nodes, but, at what point do you change the location in the HBox? Are you just translating them, switching the text, then resetting the translation? Could you just give a quick overview of how this works? That would be great!